# making a palindrome function

Tags: c++, palindrome

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

bool is_palindrome(int input[], int numOfSlots);

int main(){

int n;

cin >> n;

int *input = new int[n]; // A dynamic array with n slots

for (int i = 0 ; i < n ; i++){

     cin >> input[i];
    }

    if (is_palindrome(input,n) == true ){
        cout << "This is a palindrome.";
    }else{
        cout << "This is NOT a palindrome.";
    }
    return 0;
}

// Implement the is_palindrome() function here...
```

How do i solve the problem?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Could you give your version?

Comment: Why not give it a try and then comeback?

Comment: What is your question?? have you seen http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/29240/

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear at all .Palindrome is basically if you reverse the input then it gives same result.

Like consider an example **12321**.If you reverse this it would also give you same number.So basic `is_palindrome` implementation should be like

```
bool is_palindrome(int inputNum)
{
 int n = inputNum;
 bool isPalindrome = false;
 int digit, rev = 0;
 do
 {
     digit = inputNum%10;
     rev = (rev*10) + digit;
     inputNum = inputNum/10;
 }while (inputNum!=0);

 cout << " The reverse of the number is: " << rev << endl;
 if (n == rev)
  isPalindrome = true ;    

return isPalindrome;
}
```